# Dagger: No injectable members on android.content.Context. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by Class for Module

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I am trying to convert my singleton `CookieUtil` to be injected with Dagger into `LoginActivity`. `CookieUtil` takes an application `context` therefor I have set up the following structure :

#### AndroidModule

```
@Module(
        injects = {
            CookieUtil.class,
            LoginActivity.class
        },
        library = true
)
public class AndroidModule {
    private final App application;

    public AndroidModule(App application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    /**
     * Allow the application context to be injected but require that it be annotated with
     * {@link ForApplication @Annotation} to explicitly differentiate it from an activity context.
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ForApplication
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    CookieUtil provideCookieUtil() {
        return new CookieUtil();
    }
}
```

#### CookieUtil (What I want to inject into LoginActivity)

```
@Singleton
public class CookieUtil {
    @Inject Context mContext; // gets injected with a app context. is this right ?

    private PersistentCookieStore persistentCookieStore;

    private CookieUtil() {
      // use injected mContext
      persistentCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(mContext);
      // ...
    }
}
```

#### LoginActivity (Where I want to inject CookieUtil)

public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Inject CookieUtil cookieUtil;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // use CookieUtil ...
}
```

}

I have also set up all the bootstraping stuff from Dagger examples to enable everything to work

#### BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Perform injection so that when this call returns all dependencies will be available for use.
        ((App) getApplication()).inject(this);
    }
}
```

#### App

```
public class App extends Application {
  private ObjectGraph graph;

  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    graph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
    // ...
  }

  protected List<Object> getModules() {
    return Arrays.asList(
      new AndroidModule(this),
      new CupsModule() // Another module I haven't listed
    );
  }

  public void inject(Object object) {
      graph.inject(object);
  }

}
```

#### ForApplication

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ForApplication {
}
```

When I run the code, I get

> No injectable members on android.content.Context. Do you want to add
>   an injectable constructor? required by CookieUtil for AndroidModule

What am I doing wrong ?

Everything still looks like magic to me as I don't fully aware of how to wire everything up, so detailed explanation would be very much appreciated.

Also, would be helpful if someone could point me to an explanation on dagger modules, when does it make sense to separate into two different modules ? What logical pieces do they usually bind ?

Thanks

#### EDIT

Changed suggested by Christian Gruber

```
@Singleton
public class CookieUtil {
    private Context mContext;
    private PersistentCookieStore persistentCookieStore;

    @Inject
    public CookieUtil(Context context) {
          // use injected context
          mContext = context
          persistentCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(mContext);
          // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookie cannot have a private constructor and still be created (provisioned) by Dagger.  You can have a package-friendly constructor, and then it should work without `@Provides CookiUtil ...`.  Having the provides method for a class you control and could make injectable seems wasteful.

Generally speaking, Dagger considers a "binding" according to a "key" which is its type (with concrete type parameters, such as `Foo<Bar>`) along with any `@Qualifier`.  So the type `Foo<Bar>` is different from `@ForApplication Foo<Bar>`.  A binding is requested wherever `@Inject` occurs, and is supplied wherever `@Provides` occurs (or for unqualified bindings, if a class has an `@Inject`-marked constructor or fields, then an implicit binding is supplied.  For every `@Inject` field or constructor parameter there must be a present binding for that key.  Dagger needs to be able to see the methods it uses to create things, so generally `private` fields, methods, and constructors are not possible.

Also, please never simply inject `Context` without a qualifier.  Or better, inject `Application` or `Activity` if that's the `Context` subtype you mean.  Your graph WILL be impossible to manage if you don't distinguish between the 30,000 things that Android calls `Context` subtypes. (snark)

Comment: Thanks. (`ForApplication` was there before I haven't mentioned it, sorry) I have changed the constructor to public, and annotated it with `@Inject` instead of the member injection above. I have edited the answer a little to show my changes. Still get the same error. I want `CookieUtil` to be a wide app utility class that I can inject whenever I need (i.e. `LoginActivity`) and use as a singleton. I am new to DI and still trying to figure out my steps here. Trying to learn from examples but they are pretty scarce and the documentation assumes some level of knowledge

Comment: BTW - the snark was not at you, but the android team for having everything be a Context. :D

Comment: Understandable :) Still, i'd really like to add dagger into my project, just can't seem to find a single example that does exactly what I want (a singleton class that takes a context). I feel like i'm in the ballpark but have tried any possible combination and never seem to get it to work. About to lose hope and move on, if you have an idea what might be wrong, please share it with the rest of the world.

Comment: Um... your CookieUtil doesn't inject `@ForProvides Context` it just injects `Context`.  You need to @Provide the same type that you inject... including the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Comment: Also, I would make PersistentCookieStore in an `@Provides` method not new it up in the CookieUtil class, so you don't end up testing your PersistentCookieStore in unit tests of CookieUtil.

Comment: Thanks ! adding the qualifier solved it. Still have lots of stuff that don't sit well but at least I can start using it now and get the hang of it